# how does one get a sharpedoite and a galladite in ORAS

Tags: pokemon-omega-ruby-alpha-sapphire

I think the title is pretty self-explanatory but how do you obtain a sharpedoite? I have searched many places but cannot seem to find it. Same thing goes for the galladite, just can't find it. 
thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The location of the `Sharpedoite` *depends on your game*.

Omega Ruby: **Battle Resort**

Alpha Sapphire: **Aqua Hideout during the Delta Episode**.

As for `Galladite` you get it from **Professor Cozmo after the Delta Episode**.